# Install Zend Server on z/Linux (s390x) from Zend repos

Tags: linux, mainframe

I'm trying to install Zend Server in a z/Linux (Red Hat with kernel 2.6.18-194.el5 s390x) with

```
yum install zend-server-ce-php-5.3
```

with the repos configured as explained in [Manually Installing Zend Server page](http://files.zend.com/help/Zend-Server/rpm_installation.htm).

the s390x folder is missing in http://repos.zend.com/zend-server/rpm/

If I disabled Zend repo, enable only Zend noarch and try with:

```
yum install zend-server-ce-php-5.3-noarch
```

a lot of missed dependences from Zend are showed.

any suggestions or workarrounds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Zend Server is not provided for z/Linux.